# Sky Replacement VFX Warping Issues

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to do a simple sky replacement. I have keyed out the sky and replaced it, but the problem is that it does not match the movement of the camera. I have tried using 2D stabilization, but the replacement sky image seems to warp and doesn't match the movement of the video. I am going  by this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tq3sgUPbfk), but it does not seem to work for me. It's hard to describe the issue, but I don't know the preferred way of attaching my render.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What if you set the sky image as a sky-box? so that the tracked camera motion could take it into account and it would act like the literal sky? Or does that not work for your purposes?

Comment: @NascentSpace I don't think that would work. That's essentially what I'm doing in the compositor using the Stabilize 2D node, but it does not seem to have the desired effect. I think there is something wrong with my motion tracking, but I can't put my finger on what's causing it. The stabilization seems to almost warp the video and the rotation doesn't quite match when I key in the new sky.